# In numpy, how to sort an array with the same order with another one?

Tags: python, numpy, sorting

There are two numpy array a and w,
both of which have the same shape (d1,d2,..,dk,N).
We can think there are N sample with shape (d1,d2,...,dk).

Now, I want to sort a and w along a's last axis.

For example, a and w have shape (2,4):

```
a = [[3,2,4,1],
     [2,3,1,4]]
w = [[10,20,30,40],
     [80,70,60,50]]
sorted_index = a.argsort()
# array([[3, 1, 0, 2],
#        [2, 0, 1, 3]])
```

I want:

```
a = a.sort() # default axis = -1
# a = [[1,2,3,4],
#      [1,2,3,4]]
```

and w should be:

```
# w = [[40,20,10,30],
#      [60,80,70,50]]
```

Of course, in that case, the following code work

```
x = a.argsort()
w[0,:] = w[0,x[0]]
w[1,:] = w[1,x[1]]
```

But when the sample have many dimension (>1), that code doesn't work.
Can anyone come up with solutions? Thanks!

Comment: Could you clarify how do you want w to be sorted?

Comment: You're saying code doesn't work when dimension >1. But what you've tried for itself is greater than 1. Can you be more clear on that?

Comment: sorry , specifically, when k>1, it doesn't work, because I can't iterate each axis to sort w. @LazyCoder

Comment: a and w have the same shape. If fact, w contains the weight for each element in a. Therefore, when I sort a, I also want to sort w simultaneously.@kubatucka

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a function for that, `np.take_along_axis`:

```
>>> a = np.array([[3,2,4,1], [2,3,1,4]])
>>> w = np.array([[10,20,30,40], [80,70,60,50]])
>>> sorted_index = a.argsort()
>>> sorted_index
array([[3, 1, 0, 2],
       [2, 0, 1, 3]])
>>> np.take_along_axis(a, sorted_index, axis=-1)
array([[1, 2, 3, 4],
       [1, 2, 3, 4]])
>>> np.take_along_axis(w, sorted_index, axis=-1)
array([[40, 20, 10, 30],
       [60, 80, 70, 50]])
>>>
```

It will also work when `a` and `w` have arbitrary shape.

Comment: thanks, but it seems doesn't work when a has shape (2,2,2) because a[:, sorted_index].diagonal().T will has shape (2,2,2,2)